# Displaying a Metabox linked to post settings for all users

Tags: metabox

Currently, I have a meta box that all Editors of my site can see. I want all contributers to see this meta box.

I've used a user-role plugin and it looks like the meta box is linked to post settings. As when I enable any user to publish post they can see this meta box.

Is there a way to make this meta-box viewable by all users but still make it so contributors cant publish posts.

I'm using Tagdiv-newspaper theme and trying to get the post settings meta box to show.

I believe the meta box id is: td_post_theme_settings_metabox

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing the metabox code itself and how it works, but most likely you'd want to change the [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function to look for the [read](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#read) capability. All users -- contributors, editors, regular users -- have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This meta box is only available for users who have publish_posts capability. For enabling it to all user you need to override this meta box in themes function.php you can use "edit_post" capability

Answer (score 0):

This meta box is only available for users who have "publish_posts" capability. For enabling it to all user you need to override this meta box in themes function.php you can use "edit_post" capability

```
function add_metabox_forme(){

if ( ! class_exists( 'WPAlchemy_MetaBox' ) )
{
include_once get_template_directory_uri()  . '/includes/wp_booster/wp-admin/external/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
}
 if(current_user_can('edit_posts')  )
{
new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
            'id' => 'td_post_theme_settings',
            'title' => 'Post layout settings',
            'types' => array('post'),
            'priority' => 'high',
            'template' => get_template_directory() . '/includes/wp_booster/wp-admin/content-metaboxes/td_set_post_settings.php',
        ));
}
} 
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_metabox_forme', 40 );
```

Comment: This answer requires the use of a third party utility, which is not necessary for creating meta boxes.